# How to use a residual plot to determine if the relationship looks linear

Tags: statistics, seaborn

I was attempting some questions based on `residplot()` in seaborn. There were two residual plots in which I had to tell whether the relationship is linear. Can anyone explain how it is determined by just looking at the plot. Apparently:

[1. This plot shows the linear relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UP2lm.png)

[2. This plot shows a non-linear relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQiXA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, these residual plots enable you to visually check whether the residuals still contain some nonlinear behaviour with respect to your explanatory variables. Two remarks for further explanation:

- The residuals of a correctly specified model (e.g. the baseline linear model) should be similar to random noise. In absence of remaining patterns in the residuals, we have no indications that important features have been omitted.
- If the residuals suggest a pattern, then this means that we failed to take some (nonlinear) effects into account. You should reconsider the model specification. If the baseline model was linear, then including some nonlinear terms might "clean" the residuals.

This kind of visual inspection is often subjective. However, you can argue that 1. is just a random cloud of points whereas 2. shows some remaining curvature. There is also a statistical test to do this kind of assessment for you: the Ramsey Regression Equation Specification Error Test (RESET)